# react paypal not able to create subscriptions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, paypal, paypal-sandbox

we using react [react-paypal-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@paypal/react-paypal-js) is working fine from last year. From last week we noticed it's not working for creating subscriptions but creating payment is working fine.

`Seems like the subscription example of the React paypal js team is also not working

here are our implementations:

```
 <PayPalButtons
      createSubscription={(data, actions) => {
        return actions.subscription
          .create({
            plan_id: paypalId,
          })
          .then((orderId) => {
            return orderId
          })
      }}
      onApprove={async (data, actions) => {
        try {
```

here is the error we got:

```
{
    "ack": "contingency",
    "contingency": "RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND",
    "meta": {
        "calc": "f1031967598af",
        "rlog": "rZJvnqaaQhLn%2FnmWT8cSUueWscmrtUHe5Y1Bd%2FeqyvyOTq66rSXAciiXRg7dClMl1o2iporwJbYz7mI0k8X%2B5gW%2FmSA3nL13_18a44c050c6"
    },
    "server": "vzdyMQQX5FV78PdCUeRcVmUn1QW90MeIeVrEI5UpE6MH_xWSvIUEKhSvCznYzReT3qkMWY3GHPtIA_a2PT-y_qBFgSWRiDpfP206aTOmsJpPQnt1aeT9BsWr8-XKUjRGdFLCpvPDrNqRz11RSA2yp3YARfDRL1OgUw05Dmir8ChjvqNV_FO0JzS-sQyhOQKFQ_NuHewdgFBaDeq-QmRddPwtmJ4EZT2J4E_8ztOMCh0ZEvrDABslEm8yj3-ujdzKfuLNgKIP4EgTgSv-BCbU1bMx7OHZd5cReoQY5HEf_Yu"
}
```

API:

```
Request URL:
https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/smart/api/billagmt/subscriptions/I-332BYG89KG0S
Request Method:
GET
Status Code:
400
Remote Address:
199.232.253.21:443
Referrer Policy:
strict-origin-when-cross-origin
```

If anyone has the same issue or any suggestion please suggest. Thanks.

PayPal creates subscriptions not working.